# CSS Background property not working in pdfHTML iText7 using java

Tags: java, html, itext, itext7, html-pdf

I am trying to convert html into a pdf with the help of iText by using its method

```
HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(htmlString, pdfDocument, converterProp);
```

But it seems like this service is not honoring css properties defined in html.

Here is my html string

```
String html = "<html>"
            + "<head>"
            + "<style>"
                + "* {-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;-moz-box-sizing: border-box;box-sizing: border-box;}"
                + ".ng-hide {display: none !important;}"
                + "label { font-weight: normal; }"
                + "table { border-spacing: 0;border-collapse: collapse;}"
                + "td, th { padding: 0; }"
                + "@font-face { font-family: Muli; src: url(../fonts/Muli.woff2); }"
                + "body { font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif!important; margin: 0;padding: 0; }"
                + ".font-muli { font-family: Muli !important; }"
            + "</style>"
            + "</head>"
            + "<body>" 
            + "<div>"
                + "<div class='font-muli'>"
                    + "<div style='height: 0.69in; padding: 11px 16px; line-height: 0.49in; display: flex; font-size: 20pt;'>"
                        + "<div>"
                            + "<img style='float: left; height: 45px; margin-right: 11px;vertical-align: middle;' src='icon.png'>"
                            + "<label title='abc' class='it pull-left' style='font-style: italic;float: left;max-width: 3.6in; text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;'>abc</label>"
                        + "</div>"
                        + "<div style='font-size: 10pt;margin: auto;max-width: 12in;'>"
                            + "<table style='width: 7.5in;'>"
                                + "<tbody><tr>"
                                    + "<td>"
                                        + "<div style='text-align: center; display: grid;'>"
                                            + "<label class='' style='font-style: italic;float: left;line-height: 1.0;margin: 0;font-size: 20pt;'>1</label>"
                                            + "<label style='float: left;clear: both;line-height: 1;margin: 0 0px;text-transform: capitalize;'>abc</label>"
                                        + "</div>"
                                    + "</td>"
                                    + "<td>"
                                        + "<div style='text-align: center; display: grid;'>"
                                            + "<label style='font-style: italic;float: left;line-height: 1.0;margin: 0;font-size: 20pt;' class=''>2</label>"
                                            + "<label style='float: left;clear: both;line-height: 1;margin: 0 0px;text-transform: capitalize;' class=''>efg</label>"
                                        + "</div>"
                                    + "</td>"
                                    + "<td>"
                                        + "<div style='text-align: center; display: grid;'>"
                                            + "<label style='font-style: italic;float: left;line-height: 1.0;margin: 0;font-size: 20pt;'>3</label>"
                                            + "<label style='float: left;clear: both;line-height: 1;margin: 0 0px;text-transform: capitalize;'>jkl</label>"
                                        + "</div>"
                                    + "</td>"
                                    + "<td>"
                                        + "<div style='text-align: center; display: grid;'>"
                                            + "<label style='font-style: italic;float: left;line-height: 1.0;margin: 0;font-size: 20pt;'>4</label>"
                                            + "<label style='float: left;clear: both;line-height: 1;margin: 0 0px;text-transform: capitalize;'>afqw</label>"
                                        + "</div>"
                                    + "</td>"
                                    + "<td>"
                                        + "<div style='text-align: center; display: grid;'>"
                                            + "<label style='font-style: italic;float: left;line-height: 1.0;margin: 0;font-size: 20pt;'>5</label>"
                                            + "<label style='float: left;clear: both;line-height: 1;margin: 0 0px;text-transform: capitalize;'>qw</label>"
                                        + "</div>"
                                    + "</td>"
                                + "</tr>"
                            + "</tbody></table>"
                        + "</div>"
                    + "</div>"
                    + "<div style='background: url(../imgs/large.png) no-repeat; height: 0.12in; background-position: 0 0px; background-repeat-x: repeat;' class='mainHeaderSeparation'></div>"
                + "</div>"
            + "</div>"
            + "</body>"
}
```

And here I am converting it to pdf

```js
LicenseKey.loadLicenseFile(LICENSE);
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(destination_file);
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
pdf.addNewPage(PageSize.A2);
ConverterProperties prop = new ConverterProperties();
HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(html, pdf, prop);
```

But pdf does not have background image with repeated x. Please help me out if I am doing anything wrong? or any step is missing.
Any help/suggestion would be appreciated.

**Note: No issues with image url path, I see the image but there is not x-repeat pattern.**
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use attribute `background-image` instead of `background`

```
<div style="background-image: url(../imgs/large.png)...
```

**CSS syntax**: `<div style="background-image:url(bgimage.jpg)">`